# Using Sass, how to convert a percentage to a decimal?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

[Sass](http://sass-lang.com) has a [percentage() function](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#percentage-instance_method) to convert a unitless number to a percentage but I cannot find a function to do the reverse (percentage to decimal)

I am using the Sass [`lightness()` method](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#lightness-instance_method) to get the hue percentage. I this want to convert this percentage to a decimal value to use in specifying the transparency of a `rgba()` color.

Here’s a SCSS example which will fail to compile because `$transparent-color` requires an `$alpha` value which is a decimal, not a percentage.

```
$color: hsl(50deg, 50%, 50%);
$alpha: lightness($color);
$transparent-color: rgba(0,0,0,$alpha);
.foo { background: $transparent-color }
```

I’ve been looking for solutions in the [Sass Documentation](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/_index.html) and the [Compass Reference](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/) and know there must be a way to do this.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use Sass math to convert a percentage to a decimal value by dividing the percentage by `100%`.

When you divide a percentage by a percentage, the result is a decimal.

Sass code:

```
$percent: 44%
.foo
  opacity: $percent / 100%
```

Compiled to CSS:

```
.foo { opacity: 0.44; }
```

Answer (score 2):

While SASS doesn't provide this as a built-in function you could certainly [add a custom function](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#defining_custom_sass_functions) to perform the conversion. Taking a look at the source for percentage(), I took a stab at what a decimal() function would look like:

```
def decimal(value)
  unless value.is_a?(Sass::Script::Number) && value.unit_str == "%"
    raise ArgumentError.new("#{value.inspect} is not a percent")
  end
  Sass::Script::Number.new(value.value / 100.0)
end
```

Comment: Thanks Rhysyngsun! I edited your solution to use "100.0" instead of "100" to ensure that the result would be a float. Tested and it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

here's @Rhysyngsun ruby script as a scss function:

```
@function decimal($v) {
    @if (type_of($v) != number OR unit($v) != "%") {
        @error "decimal: `#{$v}` is not a percent";
    }
    @return $v / 100%;
}
```